# limit the number of the pagination pages

Tags: php, html, pagination

```
<?php

$limit = 1;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
$page  = $_GET["page"];
}
else{
$page=1;
};
$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM acxhuzur_dernek.video ORDER BY id LIMIT 
$start_from, $limit");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $output.='
 <div class="col-6 col-md-4 blog-post blog-post-style1 sm-margin-30px-bottom wow fadeInUp" 
 data-wow-delay="0.2s" style="margin-bottom: 30px; visibility: visible; animation-delay: 
  0.2s; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
  <div class="text-center fit-videos overflow-hidden margin-nine-bottom sm-margin-20px- 
   bottom">
  <!-- start youtube video -->
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="'.$row['video_link'].'; ?>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<!-- end youtube video -->
</div>
<div class="separator-line-verticle-small-thick bg-deep-pink d-inline-block align-top margin-three-top margin-four-left sm-margin-10px-top" style="float: right"></div>
<div class="post-details width-75 lg-width-85 d-inline-block sm-width-85 text-md-right" style="float: right">
    <a href="#" class="post-title text-medium margin-four-bottom d-block text-extra-dark-gray sm-margin-10px-bottom">'.$row['video_text'].'</a>
    <span class="post-author font-weight-500 text-extra-small text-medium-gray text-uppercase d-block margin-two-bottom">'.dateformater($row['tarih']).'</span>
</div>
</div>
'; } echo $output; ?>
```

and here is the pagination links

```
<?php
 $result_db = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM acxhuzur_dernek.video ");
 $row_db = mysqli_fetch_row($result_db);
 $total_records = $row_db[0];
 $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);
 $pagLink .= '
 <div class="col-12 margin-100px-top md-margin-50px-top wow" style="visibility: visible; 
 animation-name: fadeInUp;">
 <div class="pagination text-small text-uppercase text-extra-dark-gray text-center">
 <ul class="mx-auto">
  ';
   for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {

  if($page == $i){
  $pagLink .= '
  <li class="active"><a href="gallery_video?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>
   ';}else{ $pagLink .= '
  <li><a href="gallery_video?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>
   ';}
  }
  echo $pagLink . '</ul>
                  </div>
                 </div>

   ';
   ?>
```

This is the code I'm using to create a pagination page for data search. But I just noticed that I have too many records and it will have too many page numbers. I'm trying to limit the page number shown, and look for many examples. There are many ways to do it but I still don't have an idea how to limit it for my method.
This code is working well, but I want to limit the number of pages in the pagination block, for example,

`Prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 .. 40 41 Next`

`Prev 1 2 .. 6 7 8 9 10 .. 40 41 Next`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using any of pagination modules/libraries, e.g. https://packagist.org/?query=pagination, for the backend and any of libraries, e.g. [datatables](https://datatables.net/), for the frontend. They will save you a lot of time and problems that you will discover in the future. And they can be styled accordingly to your needs as well.